Finding the angle range of Stokes' Theorem
Given the surface $D\:=\:\left\{\left(x,\:y,\:z\right)\:in\:R^3:\:x^2+y^2=1,\:x\ge 0,\:0\le z\le h\right\}$, identify the peicewise boundary curve of D.
Here is a sketch 
And the supposed solutions 
However, I think the angle range is NOT 0 to π but rather $-π/2$ to $π/2$. This is because on the x-y graph, it is just a hemisphere centered at $0$ with $x≥0$. Which would give $-π/2$ to $π/2$.
Secondly, how do you know whether to make $sin$ or $cos$ negative in the curve parametrization? I know it varies based on the DIRECTION (clockwise or anticlockwise) but the only thing I am sure of is that a clockwise direction would mean both $sin$ and $cos$ are positive.

Look at the beginning of $\phi_1$ it starts at x=-1 so  -cos(t) should be -1 so t=0, to check the rests also look for starting and ending points of the curves may be one point in the middle to make sure.

thanks thats a good tip for my second question. Do you have an answer for my first qeustion?

The comment answers also your second question. and anticlockwise is sin and cos positiv

i said first question. About the -π/2 to π/2
